# Galaxy Avant - "Lock automatically" turns Keyguard back on

Tags: settings, lock-screens, tasker, pattern-lock, samsung-galaxy-avant

I have a new Samsung Galaxy Avant and I want to setup tasker like my old phone, specifically to turn off the Keyguard when I'm home.

It works, until the "Settings > Lock screen > Lock automatically" kicks in and turns it back on. Ive tried making another tasker action that turns Keyguard off again say, 10 seconds after the screen turns off, but that doesn't work and the Keyguard stays on. I'm not against rooting the phone, but I don't think it's needed since the Keyguard does stay off in the short time period between the display turning off and lock automatically triggering.

I'm guessing Lock automatically is a Samsung thing. Is there a way around this, or to turn off Lock automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong when I said Lock Automatically was turning the Keyguard back on. If you reopen the phone before that timer ends, the Keyguard has never been set to begin with and has nothing to do with the Tasker profile.

Anyway, to get around this I did need to root. I also needed to install [secure settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin&hl=en). With that out of the way, the setting that needs to be set on/off is Plugin > Secure Settings > Edit Configuration > Root Actions > Pattern Lock (this might be different if you are using a different type of Keyguard).

There is one last thing to note. When the Pattern Lock turns off, it reverts to whatever type of lock was being used before it turned on, so if you want it set to None, you need to have it set to that beforehand.